# The sign for "questioned equal to"

Tags: math-operators, mathjax

I want to write in TeX this sign:

## ≟

(Put in headings for bigger size).
What's the syntax?

Comment: `\stackrel{?}{=}`

Comment: What @PrzemysławScherwentke said. Or `\questeq` (or use the unicode character directly) with `\usepackage{unicode-math}`.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke:I came across this one but it seems to not render with MathJax. When trying to put it inside two $s it doesn't come out.

Comment: @ Paul Gessler: this \qesteq doesn't work in MathJax, too.

Comment: What MathJax may or may not do has nothing to do with (La)TeX!

Comment: Well, your question does not mention MathJax at all, so we didn't know you needed it at the time we wrote our comments.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentioned it, and I will try to remember that.

Comment: @UdiBehar, no worries. Note that you can always edit your question to add more details after the fact. But I'm afraid MathJax questions are largely off-topic for this site.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I work also in TeX based documents so that's all fine.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Write up an answer. [Tested on Math.SE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/99ouT.png).

Comment: Note that `\stackrel` is unknown in plain TeX. The syntax in plain TeX is `\buildrel ?\over =`. You can try if this syntax is working in MathJax (I don't know).

Comment: As @Werner noted, `\stackrel` should work with MathJax, it is on the list of supported commands: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#s If it still doesn't work for you, you can ask a question at [so]. As said above, MathJax questions are mostly off-topic here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not a long answer, and working in LaTeX, not plain TeX, but according to Werner's suggestion...

`\stackrel{?}{=}`