# What LaTeX package do I need to use \questeq?

Tags: symbols, packages

I want to use the QUESTION EQUAL TO character and the command for it is `\questeq`. I know that the "category" it is in is `mathrel`.

Comment: From here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205131/120578 you can define it using the command \def\questeq{\ensuremath{\stackrel{?}{=}}}

Comment: @koleygr Why`\def` and `\ensuremath`?

Comment: @egreg, I can't understand your question. Do you mean why combining `\def` and `\ensuremath`? Or why using each one? In first case I don't know the reason to don't do it. In second case: For `\def` no answer. For \ensuremath to be able to use it in math mode and in text mode.

Comment: @koleygr `\def` should be `\newcommand` and the symbol is for math mode, so `\ensuremath` is unnecessary (and actually wrong).

Comment: @egreg thanks for the comment... The truth is that I am using `\def` more times than the necessary (that are real few). For `\ensuremath` I added that on my edit to make sure it works in text mode because I had not seen this symbol used anywhere until now. (I don't really see the purpose of it's usage... but may be could be useful in very special cases)

Answer (score 3):

The packages [`stix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stix) and [`libertinust1math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinust1math) offer that symbol.

In Lua/XeLaTeX the symbol is additionally available with [`unicode-math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math).  Check the [list of symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) to see which fonts support `\questeq`.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex $ grep -r '\\questeq'
stix/stix.sty:\stix@MathSymbol{\questeq}                  {\mathrel}{integrals}{"90}
libertinust1math/libertinust1math.sty:\libus@MathSymbol{\questeq}                  {\mathrel}{symbols}{"70}
unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex:\UnicodeMathSymbol{"0225F}{\questeq
```

Otherwise you can build that symbol yourself using the `amsmath` package.  This is not a single symbol though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$a \overset{?}{=} b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr Okay, maybe my wording was too ambiguous.  Of course the traditional font setup also works in Lua/XeLaTeX.  *Additionally* one has the opportunity to use `unicode-math` with those.  I edited my answer accordingly.